# Python: I cannot get the right Merge Sort

Tags: python, recursion

I wrote the following programming; after running it, the result is not correct.
So what is wrong with my code?

```
def mergesort(list1):
    if len(list1) > 1:
        mid = len(list1) // 2
        left_list = list1[:mid]
        right_list = list1[mid:]
        mergesort(left_list)
        mergesort(right_list)
    i = 0 # left
    j = 0 # right
    k = 0 # total
    while len(list1) > 1 and i < len(left_list) and j < len(right_list):
        if left_list[i] < right_list[j]:
            list1[k] = left_list[i]
            k += 1
            i +=1
        else:
            list1[k] = right_list[i]
            k += 1
            j += 1
    if len(list1) > 1 and i < len(left_list):
        list1[k] = left_list[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1
    if len(list1) > 1 and j < len(right_list):
        list1[k] = right_list[j]
        k += 1
        j += 1
    return list1
        
ex = [3, 5, 9, 0, 8, 7]     
mergesort(ex)
```

result: [0, 3, 5, 7, 7, 9]

Comment: better use `print()` to see values in variables in different moments in code - and compare it with calculations on paper. This way you can find where is problem

Comment: at this moment I see one problem - you run `mergesort(left_list)` and `mergesort(right_list)` but you don't get results - `result_left = mergesort(left_list)` and `results_right =  mergesort(right_list)` -  and you don't use them.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions; it's pretty helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found three problems

1. you didn't get result from `mergesort(left_list)` `mergesort(right_list)` (but this could even work because it replaces values in original list)
2. you used `i` instead of `j`  in one place
3. you used `if` istead of `while` in two places

---

```
def mergesort(list1):
    if len(list1) > 1:
        mid = len(list1) // 2
        left_list = list1[:mid]
        right_list = list1[mid:]
        left_list = mergesort(left_list)    # 1. get result
        right_list = mergesort(right_list)  # 1. get result

    i = 0 # left
    j = 0 # right
    k = 0 # total

    while len(list1) > 1 and i < len(left_list) and j < len(right_list):
        if left_list[i] < right_list[j]:
            list1[k] = left_list[i]
            k += 1
            i +=1
        else:
            list1[k] = right_list[j]   # 2.  use `j` instead of `i`
            k += 1
            j += 1

    while len(list1) > 1 and i < len(left_list):   # 3. use `while`
        list1[k] = left_list[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1

    while len(list1) > 1 and j < len(right_list):   # 3. use `while`
        list1[k] = right_list[j]
        k += 1
        j += 1

    return list1
        
ex = [3, 5, 9, 0, 8, 7]     
print(mergesort(ex))
```

Comment: Thank you a lot; i forgot to keep the result; however, it is put in list1; maybe that  would not cause a problem; after testing it step by step, the problem is in merge steps.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 distinct steps in merge sort: the base case, the recursive step, and the merge step.  The merge step is often written as a separate function, but here I have incorporated it into the merge_sort function to stay consistent with your code.  Your biggest problem was that you did not take you recursively-sorted sub-lists and merge them.

```
def mergesort(list1):
    #base case
    if len(list1) <= 1:
        return list1

    #recursive step
    mid = len(list1) // 2
    left_list = list1[:mid]
    right_list = list1[mid:]
    sorted_left = mergesort(left_list)
    sorted_right = mergesort(right_list)

    #merge step
    result = []
    while len(sorted_left) > 0 and len(sorted_right) > 0:
        if sorted_left[0] <= sorted_right[0]:
            result.append(sorted_left.pop(0))
        elif sorted_right[0] <= sorted_left[0]:
            result.append(sorted_right.pop(0))
        else:
            result.append(sorted_left.pop(0))
            result.append(sorted_right.pop(0))

    result = result + sorted_left + sorted_right
    return result

print(mergesort([3,5,1,9,7])) #output: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: your design in merge and recursive steps are awesome~~ i am learning  it.;  thank you a lot!